# line plot with R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This shouldn't be this hard, but I am stuck. I have a table of the following form:

```
        |   1     |   2    |   3
  ------------------------------------
  TypeA |  3213   |  2121  |   43    
  TypeB |  31321  |  321   |   10
  TypeC |  332    |   11   |   9
```

And I want to generate a line plot, with three lines: one for each Type, where x-coordinates are "1,2,3", and y-coordinates are the numbers (3213, ...). I am following the steps in [here](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/line.html), but don't know how to iterate over the first column.

Comment: Consider making your example reproducible and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

If you add another column that defines they values on `x` axis, you can gather the data using `tidyr::gather` and plot it with `geom_line`. `theme_bw()` is there to remove the grey background.

```
xy <- data.frame(type = c("a", "b", "c"), one = runif(3), 
                 two = runif(3), three = runif(3), seq = 1:3)

library(tidyr)

xyg <- gather(data = xy, typ, val, -seq, -type)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(xyg, aes(x = seq, y = val, color = typ)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]